# Which Babel presets should I use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following `.babelrc` in the root directory of a React project that I build with Webpack (created with create-react-app).

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app", "env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./public/messages/"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I run the build, I get the following error

```
Syntax error: Missing class properties transform.

  1 | export default class ValidationUtils {
> 2 |   static isPhoneNumber = 'whatever'
    |   ^
  3 | }
```

If I remove `"env"` from the presets list I no longer get this error, but instead, I get an error that complains about the usage of an ES6 `import` in a script that is run as part of the build

```
/apps/my-app/scripts/mergeMessages.js:3
import * as fs from "fs";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Is there some presets setting (or anything else) that will overcome both of these issues?

Comment: I wrote an article recently https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-conquer-webpack-4-and-build-a-sweet-react-app-236d721e6745 there is a babel configuration in it, that handles your use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `transform-class-properties` plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

You babelrc will then look like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app", "env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./public/messages/"
      }
    ],
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```